# How may I show an HTML file in a TWebBrowser component?

Tags: html, c++, twebbrowser, c++builder-xe8

I'm using C++ Builder XE8. I want to show 4 HTML files in a `TWebBrowser` component.

How may I show an HTML file in a `TWebBrowser` component?

Comment: Can you post some code with what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have nothing, I just received this earlier today and I'm doing some research but nothing solid, I never got the chance to do something like this until now, please, help!

Comment: `TWebBrowser` has a `Navigate()` method, simply pass the path to the desired HTML file to it. [Read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Twebbrowser)

Comment: DAMN!!! you're right!! problem solved! thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Given you already have created a `TWebBrowser` component and named it WebBrowser1, use the following code.

```
WebBrowser1->Navigate("insertPathToHtmlFileHere");
```

Remy Lebeau mentioned documentation. Below are two helpful sources.

Sources to check out:
[Building a VCL Forms Web Browser Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Building_a_VCL_Forms_Web_Browser_Application)
[TWebBrowser.Navigate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.Navigate)